# Which conditional if sentence should I use in this situation?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> A: I can know the future. You better not to call the police.
>
> B: If you really **knew** the future, you **would know** that I've already
>   called the police.

After googling, For speaker (B), I excluded conditional Zero and one. I chose conditional two as it is hypothetical but I'm not sure about that. Would help me, please? Should I use any continuous tense or something?

> B: If you **were** really **knew** the future, you **would know** that I've already
>   called the police.

I need the answer to be colloquial American. There's no need for traditional rules. Thank you,

Comment: (were_knew) is wrong since they are two main verbs. (knew) alone is correct. If you want to use a continuous tense, you would better write (If you were really knowing the future) but I doubt that the past continuous tense is suitable for your sentence because the verb **know** happens once when a person realizes a fact, that knowledge will continue as long as the person is alive. All in all, your first B's sentence is correct.

Comment: @TasneemZh Thank you so much for this comment. It answers my questions and it adds more info. Please, write it as an answer so I can give it the best answer. Thank you once again for your useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was saying, this sentence:

> B: If you were really knew the future, you would know that I've
>   already called the police.

is not correct, since it has **were** - main verb number 1, and **knew** - main verb number 2.

You mentioned that you were trying to make it continuous, so you should write it like this:

> B: If you were really knowing the future, you would know that I've
>   already called the police.

However, that is not correct either, since the past continuous for the verb **know** happens once when a person realizes a fact; thus, he will gain specific knowledge about a certain issue. *That knowledge* will continue as long as the person is alive.

For your first B's sentence:

> B: If you really knew the future, you would know that I've already
>   called the police.

is totally correct as you have used the right tense in it with only one main verb.